# I was hoping someone could give m advice on the best way to this solution?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am updating a website for my client.  The web site has a store locator page, there are around 65,000 store locations in this store location page.  They are all stored within a MySql database inthe storeLocation table.

This feature works great, everything is fine, however, my clients wants to give the ability for users to filter the store locations to which locations carry which products.

So we have 7 total products that would be used as filters.  I was thinking about using some kind of mapping table, maybe like a one to many....one store location can hold many products.  I am trying to think of a quick way to link the locations table to the new mapping table.

The only solution I have came up with so far is making the table and then having to go through each store adding which products they carry.  I would like to be able to query against some kind of order history table that has the product names that the store ordered, this would allow me to create a php script to link the tables. I have not found said table, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what client this is but I am impressed that 65,000 stores carry their products, kudos!

I would do the following:

**stores**

- 65,000 entries of stores with a unique ID for each one

**products**

- 7 entries of unique products with a unique ID and product name

**store_products**

- 65,000 - 455,000 entries of a store ID and one or all seven product IDs

Answer (score 0):

I'm just wondering, the order history isnt' really relevant. Even if a store ordered an items, it's not 100% sure it's still in stock. The store-website could flag if it is in-store or not, but for the filter-location I wouldn't take that into account. If the store has or had the item I would include it.

Comment: I think the order history table will be used to populate the products table initially so that Jacob does not have to do it manually for 65,000 locations

Comment: I'm not sure if that information will be still accurate enough for a 65.000 location - merchandise, but ok :)

Comment: I don't think OP is looking to manage inventory levels. Based on the post, his company sells products a, b, c, d, e, f, and g. There are stores which put in orders to stock their shelves with these products. OP is just looking to say "Hey Look! These 10,000 stores carry a, c, and d but 55,000 carry d, e, f, and g". So now the user should call **that** store to figure out inventory levels

Answer (score 0):

Have mapping tables.
one store can have multiple products. also a product can belong to multiple stores.
Table Structure:

products
id, name, desc, status(enum active/inactive), ...

stores
id, name, location, status(enum active/inactive) ... 

product_store
id, store_id, product_id, status(enum active/inactive),...

action_history
id, store_id, product_id, comments, timestamp, ...

By having product_store table, you will be able to find the mappings of store to product or product to store (can have many to many.. this will add scalability).
Also, You can track down, using action_history table whenever you assign a product to a store or viceversa, just add that action log in that table.

Inshort,
action_history will have action logs of assigning product to store.
and product_store with status active will tell you currently which all products belong to which all stores.